# Memory leak in asynctask called repeatedly

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

Can there be any memory leak in below mentioned code ??

inside timer function with delay of 1000ms.

```
new AsyncProcessing().execute(new TestReceive(bytes,datas));
```

Inner Class

```
public class AsyncProcessing extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... r) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*
        byte[] data = passing[0].toString().getBytes();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(passing[1].toString());
        int id = Integer.parseInt(passing[2].toString());*/

            TestReceive ra = (TestReceive)r[0];

            //  System.out.println("res val "+bytArrayToHex(data));
            //  System.out.println("func enter : "+ra.ids);
            func(ra.data,ra.size);
            //  System.out.println("func exit : "+ra.ids);
            ra = null;

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ra` is an object that contains native calls, then yes, absolutely that can have a memory leak. Typically such native code contains a `.dispose()` or `.release()` or `.clean()` method (typically all synonymous), look up the documentation about managing your memory for that object.

Comment: TestReceive class only has only 2 data members namely String data and int size . no native calls are made from its object , only getters and setters. But right now i am accessing them directly. 

I was wondering when objects of AsyncProcessing class will be grabage collected .

Comment: Java has active garbage collection on Java code, so it is collected constantly. It would actually be very difficult to create a memory leak in Android, but it is entirely possible. In this case, I do not think it is at all likely that this code would create a leak. The Async class itself is collected after its `onPostExecute`, with objects created inside it destroyed when it is done running. One thing to note about this code is it doesn't create new objects, it references existing ones. `ra=null` does not destroy anything.